# Injection from the permutation representation of $S_4$ to $\uparrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2}$?

Tags: representation-theory, proof-verification

Let $V$ denote the permutation representation of $S_4$. I want to know if there is an injection $\alpha: V \rightarrow \space \uparrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2} 1$.

**My Answer:**
I don't think we can find such an $\alpha$. We have,

$$V \cong k \times k \times k \times k$$ for some algebraically closed field $k$. We also have $$\uparrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2} 1 \cong k[S_4/(S_2 \times S_2)] = k\bar{1} \oplus k\overline{(1 2)} \oplus k\overline{(1 3)} \oplus k\overline{(2 3)} \oplus k\overline{(1 2 3)}  \oplus k\overline{(1 3 2)}$$ where $\overline{(x_1, ... ,x_m)}$ denotes the equivalence class of $(x_1, ... , x_m)$.

In order to have an injection, we need to map $V$ isomorphically to a $4$ dimensional subgroup of $\uparrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2} 1$. But that's impossible, since any subgroup of dimension $4$ is not invariant under the action of $S_4$ (since the action permutes the equivalence classes). For example, if we map $V$ into $k\bar{1} \oplus k\overline{(1 2)} \oplus k\overline{(1 3)} \oplus k\overline{(2 3)}$, we have

$$(1 2 4 3)(k\bar{1} \oplus k\overline{(1 2)} \oplus k\overline{(1 3)} \oplus k\overline{(2 3)} \\ = k\overline{(1 2 4 3)} \oplus k\overline{(1 4 3)} \oplus k\overline{(2 4 3)} \oplus k\overline{(1 2)(4 3)} \\ = k\overline{(1 4)} \oplus k\overline{(1 3 2)} \oplus k\overline{(1 2 3)} \oplus k\overline{1}$$

and we know that $k\overline{(1 2 3)}$ and $k\overline{(1 3 2)}$ are not contained in $k\bar{1} \oplus k\overline{(1 2)} \oplus k\overline{(1 3)} \oplus k\overline{(2 3)}$.

Is my answer correct? If not, can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: First, are you working over $\mathbb{C}$ or some arbitrary field? Also, your representatives for the cosets of $S_2\times S_2$ are not correct since $(12)\in S_2\times S_2$. Finally, not all submodules need to come from picking $4$ of those basis vectors (after all, that is not how you usually get the trivial module inside the permutation module).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am working over any algebraically closed field. Thanks for answering, but I'm not sure why you say $(1 2) \in S_2 \times S_2$. Isn't $S_2 \times S_2 = \{(1), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. Also, yes the trivial (and standard) representations are not obtained that way...I forgot about that.

Comment: While that is a subgroup isomorphic to $S_2\times S_2$ it is a somewhat unusual way to embed it into $S_4$ (to me the most natural choice would be $\{(1),(12),(34),(12)(34)\}$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft We see that $\langle \uparrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2} 1_{S_2 \times S_2}, 1_{s_4} \rangle = \langle 1_{S_2 \times S_2}, \downarrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2} 1_{S_4} \rangle = \frac{1}{4}(1 + 1 + 1 + 1) = 1$. If $\uparrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2}$ is irreducible, we are done (b/c it tells us the induced representation is the same as the trivial one, and obviously does not contain the permutation representation). If its not irreducible, let $\uparrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2} 1_{S_2 \times S_2}= V_1 \oplus ... \oplus V_n$ for some n, where the $V_i$ are irreducible. I'll continue below.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Denote the induced representation by $W$, and the trivial representation of $S_2 \times S_2$ by $W'$ for simplicity. By the properties of the characters, we have $\langle \chi_W, \chi_{W'} \rangle = \langle \chi_{V_1}, \chi_{W'} \rangle + ... + \langle \chi_{V_n}, \chi_{W'} \rangle = 1$ Since each of $\langle \chi_{V_i}, \chi_{W'} \rangle$ is either $0$ or $1$, we see that $W'$ must be a submodule of $W$. I'll continue.

Comment: Denote the standard representation of $S_4$ by $V^{st}$. Now we get $\langle \uparrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2} 1_{S_2 \times S_2}, V^{st} \rangle = \langle 1_{S_2 \times S_2}, \downarrow^{S_4}_{S_2 \times S_2} V^{st} \rangle = 0$. So the standard representation of $S_4$ is not contained in the induced representation, which means that the permutation representation is not contained either.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Actually, the last comment I wrote is sufficient for the answer, right?

Comment: @Artos It would be sufficient but I'm afraid it is not true in general. At least sending $1$ to $(1,1,1,1)$ is a homomorphism from $1_{S_2\times S_2} \to \downarrow_{S_2\times S_2}^{S_4} V^{st}$. (It is not immediate whether the homomorphism $\uparrow_{S_2\times S_2}^{S_4} 1_{S_2 \times S_2} \to V^{st}$ corresponding to the above is injective)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work over a field of characteristic $0$ or a commutative ring that contains $\mathbb Q$ the representation theory of $S_n$ is the same as over $\mathbb C$. Let me assume this.

In this case a lot is known about the induction from $S_a\times S_b$ to $S_{a+b}$. (See e.g. Fulton-Harris p. 58 (4.41), pp.455f (A.7) and (A.8))

I would calculate the decomposition of both $S_4$ representations (using (A.7) for the induced representation).

My solution:

> In particular it can be computed by Pieri's rule (A.7) that
>  $ \uparrow_{S_2\times S_2}^{S_4} 1_{S_2\times S_2} \cong V_{(4)}\oplus V_{(3,1)} \oplus V_{(2,2)}.$
>  (Here $V_\lambda$ is the irreducible $S_4$-representation corresponding to $\lambda$.)
>  It is well-known (and much easier to see) that
>  $V^{st} \cong V_{(4)}\oplus V_{(3,1)} .$
>  Putting both results together one knows that there is an injection of $V^{st}$ to $\uparrow_{S_2\times S_2}^{S_4} 1_{S_2\times S_2}$. But I have no idea how it looks like.
>  (The map described in my comment is therefore not injective.)